# the graph is invisible in highcharts with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm trying to get the highcharts with php by using sample code from highcharts.com. But my line graph is not visible when loading the code. Let me know any solution.
below is my code:

index.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 


<title>Using Highcharts with PHP and MySQL</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2    /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themes/gray.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Hourly Visits',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
                        tickWidth: 0,
                        gridLineWidth: 1,
                        labels: {
                            align: 'center',
                            x: -3,
                            y: 20,
                            formatter: function() {
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Visits'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x-(1000*3600)) +'-'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x) +': <b>'+ this.y + '</b>';
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Count'
                    }]
                }
                // Load data asynchronously using jQuery. On success, add the data
                // to the options and initiate the chart.
                // This data is obtained by exporting a GA custom report to TSV.
                // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
                jQuery.get('data.php', null, function(tsv) {
                    var lines = [];
                    traffic = [];
                    try {
                        // split the data return into lines and parse them
                        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                        jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                            line = line.split(/\t/);
                            date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                            traffic.push([
                                date,
                                parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                            ]);
                        });
                    } catch (e) {  }
                    options.series[0].data = traffic;
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

data.php

```
 <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Verizon123");

 if ($con->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " .      $con->connect_error); } echo "Connected successfully", "<br />";

 mysqli_select_db($con,"douresult");

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM highcharts_php");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['timespan'] . "\t" . $row['visits']. "\n"."<br />";
  }

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

here is the output for data.php

Connected successfully
Friday, July 1, 2011 01:00:00 1288
Friday, July 1, 2011 02:00:00 1275
Friday, July 1, 2011 03:00:00 1270
Friday, July 1, 2011 04:00:00 1279
Friday, July 1, 2011 05:00:00 1268
Friday, July 1, 2011 06:00:00 1267
Friday, July 1, 2011 07:00:00 1271
Friday, July 1, 2011 08:00:00 1287
Friday, July 1, 2011 09:00:00 1276
Friday, July 1, 2011 10:00:00 1278
Friday, July 1, 2011 11:00:00 1272
Friday, July 1, 2011 12:00:00 1288
Friday, July 1, 2011 13:00:00 1264
Friday, July 1, 2011 14:00:00 1280
Friday, July 1, 2011 15:00:00 1277
Friday, July 1, 2011 16:00:00 1278
Friday, July 1, 2011 17:00:00 1279
Friday, July 1, 2011 18:00:00 1277
Friday, July 1, 2011 19:00:00 1270
Friday, July 1, 2011 20:00:00 1264
Friday, July 1, 2011 21:00:00 1278
Friday, July 1, 2011 22:00:00 1284
Friday, July 1, 2011 23:00:00 1272

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking the error console? check if your php code actually outputs anything?

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for Highcharts not showing up, however the most common would be it's not receiving the data so it can't build the chart, so as Marc suggested, take a look at error logs and see if you can find anything regarding that.

Comment: it get the output correctly which is above. i'm new to this can you help me how to check the error logs?

Comment: on the graph i can see the "Hourly Visits" on the top and "Count" on the right and "visits" on the left but not the lines...

Comment: it should show the graph like this: http://blueflame-software.com/demo/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: The output you shown has dates only no value data is in your output. See the date format as well

Comment: @ Nishith what value i'm missing...this is exactly from here:https://blueflame-software.com/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: In the PHP you can return data as json (json_encode). Then in javascript use $.getJSON(). Next advice is use timestamps instead of dates which you have. To do that in PHP you have strtotime() function.

Comment: @SebastianBochan so i have to remove JQuery.get and replace with $.getJSON(). ? when i tried that it displayed blank page

Comment: Do you prepared a json in php? How looks like ?

Comment: how do you mean by prepare json in php? i'm new to this. can you give me the whole code?

Comment: @SebastianBochan any solution?

Comment: In the php manual, you have examples how to create a json. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php